# Tabulator - Can addRow be used with AJAX like setData?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabulator

I'm still using Tabulator 3.5...

Is it possible to add a row to tabulator `addRow` with the row object being returned via AJAX like it is when setting data `setData`?

IE, instead of:

```
$("#picks-table").tabulator("addRow", {"player":"La Di Da", "owner":"Some Spud"},true);
```

I'd like to use:

```
$("#picks-table").tabulator("addRow", "updateDraftPicks.php",true);
```

where the output of updateDraftPicks.php script is:

```
{"player":"La Di Da", "owner":"Some Spud"}
```

I'm thinking it isn't possible, but just wanted to be sure I'm not doing something wrong before trying more complex work arounds.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible directly with Tabulator.

The correct approach would be to make the ajax request yourself and then call the addRow function with the returned data.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I ended up just setting the data of the whole table, including the new row, using Tabulator's AJAX module as it is only a small table.